# How do i tie my sql query into my vb code so that my combo boxes will be in alphabetical order when i hit drop down button

Tags: sql, vb.net

I tried using the sort function but it won't let me since im connected to a datasource.

Here is my code for that section:

```
Private Sub ClientIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.SA_CLient order by CLientname"
    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    con.Close()



End Sub
```

Comment: Your query does return sorted result - what seems to be the problem?

Comment: where's the code to fill the combobox?

Comment: I am using a data source

Comment: If your combobox's `Sorted` property is set to False and your query comes back sorted (as shown in your sample code), then you should be good to go....